# Problem with scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add a working Tikz picture in another.
PGF and Tizk related uses are :

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
```

In case it could generate some problems, I precise that
I also use

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

My code is

```
     \begin{tikzpicture} 
     \begin{axis}[
         axis lines=middle,
         xlabel=Quantité initiale de $^{87}$Sr,
         ylabel=$\frac{^{87}Sr}{^{86}Sr}$,
         xmin=0, xmax=4,
         ymin=0, ymax=3,
         enlargelimits=true,
         clip=false,
         width=24cm,
         height=12cm,
         domain=0:3,
         samples=100,
        smooth,
        yticklabel=\empty,
         xticklabel=\empty,
         xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
         ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
         ]
         \draw[dashed,red] (axis cs:0,0.5) -- (axis cs:4.3,0.5);   
\begin{scope}[shift={(axis cs:1,1)}]
           \begin{axis}[
             width=5cm,
             height=5cm,
             xmin=-1, xmax=1,
             ymin=-1, ymax=1,
             enlargelimits=true,
             axis lines=middle,
             ]
             \addplot[red,thick] {x^2};
          \end{axis}
         \end{scope}   
    \end{axis}   
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Each picture is ok when alone. When I compile it I got the message :

> ! Package PGF Math Error: The function `thisrow' already exists.
>
> See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.184         ]
> ```

What is wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not nest `axis` or `tikzpicture`s to the point where you just need to remember *never* to do it.

I believe that this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
width=24cm, height=12cm,
xmin=0, xmax=4,
ymin=0, ymax=3,
enlargelimits=true,
xticklabel=\empty, yticklabel=\empty,
]
\draw[red, dashed] (0,0.5) -- (4.3,0.5); 
\coordinate (axis2) at (1,1);   
\end{axis}   
\begin{axis}[
at=(axis2),
width=5cm, height=5cm,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
enlargelimits=true,
axis lines=middle,
]
\addplot[red, thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: One axis inside an other and a small red parabola]

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I will try to adapt your solution to the more complicated stuff I really want to do and I'll come back.

Comment: Great! It does exactly what I wanted to do. Many thanks.